# scikit-learn MinMax scaler doesn't scale

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, bigdata

How to scale the scikit-learn function MinMaxScaler if I have a big array ?
So let's define the following

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
```

and let's consider the following datasets

```
Y_train # shape = (2358331,1)
X_train # shape = (2358331,302)
```

Now I can scale my Y_train using

```
%%time
Y_train = scaler.fit_transform(Y_train)
```

it works fine and I get

```
CPU times: user 36.3 ms, sys: 104 ms, total: 141 ms
Wall time: 388 ms
```

But when I use the same command for X_train, it takes forever, it seems that the execution time is not linear with respect to the number of column.
So I tried to use a loop to execute the scaler for each feature.

```
for i in range(X_train.shape[1]):
  scaled_feature = 
    scaler.fit_transform(X_train[:,i].reshape(X_train.shape[0],1))
  X_train[:,i] = scaled_feature.reshape(X_train.shape[0],)
```

But it's also endless.
My question is why is it that way ? And do you have an alternative for this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that you're operating on a huge amount of data.

`MinMaxScaler` takes a parameter `copy`, which is `True` by default. That means it'll make a copy of your data. And your data is *huge*. Assuming conservatively that every data point is a 32-bit integer, `X_train` is about 2.8 gigabytes. All of that is getting funneled into memory and copied. You're getting stuck in the copying phase because of [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)).

How do you mitigate this?

1. Call the constructor with `copy=False`.
2. If that’s not enough of an improvement, check out [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html), which lets you access large data stored in memory.

Comment: Thanks, the constructor copy=False did the job